# Por que mi cambio de vista con el "v-bind:href="" " se queda en blanco?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Estoy haciendo un cambio de vista utilizando vue.js y ruby on rails, al momento de hacer el cambio solo hace el salto de vista pero no carga la vista este es el codigo para que se den una idea:

routes.rb :

```
get 'programas/:slug/videos/:slug' => "programs#index"
```

vista.vue :

```
<div v-for="video in videos_p">
        <a v-bind:href="'/programas/' + video.program.slug + '/videos/' + video.slug"><img v-bind:src="video.image_url" alt=""></a>
        <h3 class="post_title"> </h3>
        <a href="#">{{video.name}}</a>
</div>
```

esta el vista como la llama:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si refresco la vista si hace la recarga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
alguna idea de que puede estar haciendo este tipo error????

Comment: ¿Muestras los logs del servidor en las dos llamadas?

Comment: Verifico la consola pero solo carga informacion de la primera vista, cuando cambio de vista mantiene la misma informacion hasta que recargo la vista

Comment: Estas usando vue-router?

Comment: No, para eso estoy utilizando las rutas de rails ya que estoy jalando el nombre del programa y el slug del video, como muestro en la informacion de arriba